# Could not import models from the same folder in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I cannot import my models in my `api/views.py` of my products app. Every folders and subfolders are shown in the image here.

[image: Products app Image]

My `api\views.py` is:

```py
from  products.models import *
    
class CategoryAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Category (cant import Category)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There is no suggestion given for the model Category in queryset. Also, there is a red underline in products.

Comment: Did you get any error or are just asking the question because VS code didn't show the suggestion and showed up a red underline?

Comment: So no actual error just your IDE not being able to handle `import *` imports?

Comment: When I removed * and replaced with Category, it still shows red underline...does red underline affetcs the code later??

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to parent directory to import models. Try this code, hopefully it will work.

```
from .. import models

class CategoryAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.Category
```